# const template parameter does not retain const-ness after creation

Tags: c++, templates, constants

Why doesn't `width` retain its `const`ness after the first instantiation?

```
template<typename T, const std::size_t N>
class ProjectionTest
{
    std::array<T, N*N> _arr;
public:
    ProjectionTest() : width(N)
    { }

    const std::size_t width = 0;

};

ProjectionTest<int, 9> test;
ProjectionTest<int, test.width> test2;
```

It gives error:
Error   C2975   'N': invalid template argument for 'ProjectionTest', expected compile-time constant expression

Comment: use `constexpr` for that. or `static const`

Comment: I had tried constexpr, it gives Error C2126 'ProjectionTest<T,N>::width' cannot be declared with 'constexpr' specifier. Didn't try static const, but it gave Error C2438 'width': cannot initialize static class data via constructor

Comment: Err, it'd have to be `static constexpr`. What you defined is a non-static member,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The non-static member `width` is constant, but not compile-time constant, which is needed for template argument.

You could use `constexpr` (which has to be static member), e.g.

```
template<typename T, const std::size_t N>
class ProjectionTest
{
    std::array<T, N*N> _arr;
public:
    ProjectionTest()
    { }

    constexpr static std::size_t width = N;

};
```

then

```
ProjectionTest<int, test.width> test2;
```

[LIVE with VC](http://rextester.com/JVG55222)

Comment: Note that you have to make it a static member

Comment: Thank you that worked. I thought that width would retain its value (because its static) across instantiations with different widths, but it didn't.

Comment: @gjohnson No, every instantiated template class with different template argument is irrelevant. So, `ProjectionTest<int, 9>::width` and `ProjectionTest<int, 7>::width` are two independent things.